# What is the limit of the Death Eraser?

Tags: death-note

The [Death Note Wikia](http://deathnote.wikia.com) states that...

> 1. The Death Eraser can revive the people that have been killed by the note
> 2. The Death Eraser is an artefact

In the wikia is also states  if you wrote "dies from a tragic accident or something",would the person's wounds or destroyed body parts be healed?

Which lead me to ask what is the limits of the Death Eraser and if you wrote "commits suicide by gun" and you used the Death Eraser to bring them back, would the wounds heal even though they come back to life?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, [The Death Eraser](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Eraser) is a plot device exclusive to [the manga pilot.](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_Manga_Pilot)

> Death Note includes a rule stating that if the owner of the notebook uses the Death Eraser to erase names in the Death Note, the victims come back to life if they have not been cremated.

With this said we know atleast a body is needed for this

> Taro Kagami is offered the Death Eraser by Ryuk, and is told that he can erase the names in the Death Note and the victims will miraculously come back to life

Using the description Miraculously make's it quiet easy for them to get away with just about anything. They are miraculously healed, or the miraculously live on as just a severed head.

Simply said, It all comes down to the fact its a miracle.

Comment: i never know about Death Eraser before!!!!! thanks for the info....... +1 to ur answer

Answer (score 4):

I doubt the "Death Eraser" exist (I actually haven't found references in any plot of the official manga/anime), since the Shikigami, who are the original owners of the notes, gets the remaining human life span and adds it to themself. Something that could revive humans would alter fundamentally the propose of the Death Note, and such thing was not devisable by the mangaka.

I remember you that wikia is a fan-made site and references and claims are not official nor accurate.

Comment: The Death Eraser is pretty real all right.

Comment: The Death Eraser existed, but only in the pilot manga. It never made it into the actual series, so I doubt the limitations were developed too much.

Comment: @Ken obviously we are going to hit several plot holes trying to figure out the usage of the Death Eraser. The answer above is under the main plot.

Comment: @oncer12_shawn (see above comment)

Answer (score 0):

The "death eraser" only made it as far as the pilot manga. This is understandable considering that if it would have made it into the actual series it would have caused major contradictions. The fact that the death note ever exists would contradict the existence of the "death eraser" If the death note was made to add life to a Shinigami than would the death eraser take away from the Shinigami's lifespan? That's probably the reason that the "death eraser" never made it to the official series: it would cause too many problems that would have to be worked out and explained. By the time that everything was explained we would already be about 2 episodes in. Nobody would want to watch that content. So in the long run, taking the "death eraser" out of the series completely would be the best solution.